# Will a decimal with 10 Precision always occupy 9 bytes in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, decimal

On this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28v=sql.80%29.aspx it is mentioned that decimal with 10-19 precision will occupy 9 bytes. So does this mean if I define decimal(10,2) colum inside sql server 2008, and I store two values on the database:-

1. 12345678.91
2. 12.34

So will each of the above two numbers occupy 9 bytes regardless of their size, and if this is the case then which data type can give me more efficient storage allocation so 12.34 will occupy less than 12345678.91?

Regards

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using? If Enterprise `vardecimal` is available though this is deprecated in favour of general compression.

Comment: That is version not edition (Standard, Express, Enterprise)?

Answer (score 1):

Storage is based on data type not value

Both numbers will require 9 bytes

Comment: so is there a more efficient data type in respect to dynamically occupying storage.

Comment: @johnG: Without adding an overhead and idiocy of using say, varchar then no. Have you a performance problem or are you doing premature optimisation? I've had no issues with tables with billions of rows...

Comment: @johnG: use decimal then as normal, and see how it goes. Proper indexing and normalisation goes a lot further then micromanaging bytes used per datatype